# How to auto scroll down RecyclerViews latest item when Realm db item added

Tags: android, realm

I am successfully adding items to a realm db and populating a Recyclerview through the adapter and updating the view with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Works ok.

The problem is after the list fills the view, the new items appear *below* the scrolled space. I want the view to update to have the newest item already at the bottom without the user having to scroll down, else they miss that a new item has been added at all.

For example if I click to add 5 items I want the 5 items to be the bottom 5 rows on the screen already, no scroll needed.

Any ideas how to do this properly, preferably without hacks to force the scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason neither of the answers so far worked, perhaps because it is a RecyclerView? This is the only thing that eventually worked for scrolling down to the latest item for me, incidentally a Realm db but could be a list/array.

Instantiated on onCreateView:

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

The command that does the scroll correctly on the RecyclerView, called on onChange

```
mLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView, null, results.size());
```

I don't know why the above answers scrollToPositionWithOffset and scrollToPosition simply don't work on RecyclerView, anyone who could explain appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After your `notifyDataSetChanged()` call `myList.scrollToPosition(myArray.size - 1);`

[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)) you find method doc

Answer (score 0):

Try using `scrollToPositionWithOffset(int position, int offset)` or simply `scrollToPosition(int position)`
You may also need to cast LayoutManager of recyclerview to LinearLayoutManager, if using GridLayoutManager
For Eg
    ((LinearLayoutManager)getLayoutManager())

recyclerView.scrollToPositionWi‌thOffset(listSize - 1, 0);

Answer (score 0):

You  can also use

```
recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(recyclerview.getAdapter().getItemCount());
```